# Model categories: $\text{Ho}$ and $\cal C_{cf}/\sim$

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, fibration, cofibrations

I have asked this question about model categories:

Why $\text{Ho} \ \cal C$ is $\cal C_{cf}/\sim$ and not $\cal C/\sim$ and I got this answer:
take for cofibratiobns Iso, weak equivalences all arrows. Then $\text{Ho}\ \cal C$ is $1$.
Then $f \sim g$ for all f,g where $f \sim g$ means that $f$ and $g$ are homtopic.
If $\cal C$ is poset, $\cal C/\sim$ is $\cal C$.

```
Now I wonder why cofibrations should be Iso, is this 
(and even the notion of cofibration) used in any way in the above?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the choice of model category is that

1. all morphisms are weak equivalences, so that $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal C$ is readily equivalent to $1$ (note that this relies on $\mathcal C$ having for example an initial object, since this fails for "disconnected" categories as Zhen Lin pointed out), but also all pairs of parallel morphisms are homotopic (to see this, note that a cylinder object $X\amalg X\rightarrowtail\operatorname{Cyl}X\twoheadrightarrow X$ is necessarily isomorphic to $X\amalg X$ and thus any pair of parallel morphisms admit a left homotopy between them), showing that $\mathcal C/\sim$ will not necessarily be equivalent to $1$ (the explicit example they give is to take $\mathcal C$ to be a posetal category, in which case homotopy of maps is just given by equality and therefore $\mathcal C/\sim$ is exactly the same as $\mathcal C$)
2. the only cofibrant objects are initial in $\mathcal C$, so that $\mathcal C_{c}$ (and thus $\mathcal C_{cf}/\sim$) is also readily equivalent to $1$, showing that this is correct in creating the homotopy category of $\mathcal C$

The answer you were given was emphasising how taking $\mathcal C/\sim$ is *wrong* (which doesn't require the cofibrations). Seeing how $\mathcal C_{cf}/\sim$ is *right* requires the cofibrations essentially by definition.

While this answer certainly provides a concrete counterexample for your question, I'll provide a softer reason why one would want to restrict their attention to $\mathcal C_{cf}$.
Note that the notion of homotopy is not that well-defined over general objects: there are two notions of homotopy (left homotopy with cylinder objects and right homotopy with path objects), and we don't know a priori whether they coincide.
Perhaps you could remedy this by taking $\sim$ to be the equivalence relation generated by both kinds of homotopy, but such a thing would be incredibly difficult to study.
However, when you restrict your attention to nicer objects, you get a cleaner notion of homotopy theory:

> If $X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is fibrant, then the notions of left and right homotopy on $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,Y)$ coincide and define an equivalence relation.

(for a proof, see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+in+a+model+category))
Therefore, if we restrict our attention to $\mathcal C_{cf}$, the relation $\sim$ becomes much easier to work with: if $f\sim g$, then it admits a left *and* a right homotopy, and you are free to use either one to reason with it!
What's most important, though, is that we get an analogue of [Whitehead's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+category+of+a+model+category#universal_property):

> If $X$ and $Y$ are cofibrant fibrant, then a weak equivalence $X\to Y$ is automatically a homotopy equivalence $X\simeq Y$.

Showing that $\mathcal C_{cf}/\sim$ *will* convert weak equivalences to isomorphisms.

It's also important to note: you can technically make sense of a homotopy category just using the weak equivalences (see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+category#for_categories_with_weak_equivalences)), defining it by being universal with the property that the image of weak equivalences in $\mathcal C\to\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal C$ are isomorphisms. We can even define it explicitly, by taking $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal C$ to be the category with the same objects as $\mathcal C$, but whose morphisms $X\to Y$ are given by zigzags
$$
X\gets\gets\to\gets\to\dots\to\to\gets Y
$$
where all left-pointing arrows are given by weak equivalences and are thought of as formal inverses to the weak equivalence.
However, at this level of generality, the homotopy category could be extremely large, and extremely difficult to control. Part of the motivation for studying a model category is that the auxiliary data provided by cofibrations and fibrations makes it easier to study the homotopy category ($\mathcal C_{cf}/\sim$ is a much better-behaved category). Therefore, one would *expect* that the cofibrations and fibrations would play a significant role when defining $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal C$; if we just used $\mathcal C/\sim$, then what good were the cofibrations and fibrations?

Comment: I have tried hard but I couldn't make sense of your last sentence: "if we just used $\cal C/ \sim$, then what good were the cofibrations and fibrations?" I think that my English is poor at this point.

Comment: I mean that $\mathcal C/\sim$ doesn't use the cofibrations and fibrations, so if this were sufficient to define the homotopy category, then we wouldn't have needed the cofibrations and fibrations in the first place

Comment: Right, but $\text{Ho}\ \cal C$ doesn't need the fibrations and cofibrations as well ?

Comment: Not in general, but I was remarking about why one would use model categories at all to study the homotopy category in the first place: these auxiliary classes of morphisms make computations worlds easier

Comment: @shibai It is not obvious that $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$ is contractible. For example, it is true when $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object, but not when $\mathcal{C}$ is a disjoint union of two subcategories.

Comment: @ZhenLin sure but a model category is at least finitely cocomplete by assumption, so I didn't think to make a big deal about it, though thank you for bringing it up; I'll make note of it

Comment: Connectedness is not enough, though. For example, not every connected groupoid is contractible (= simply connected, for groupoids).

Comment: @ZhenLin you're definitely right, but I never said connectedness was enough (and this seems to be getting off-topic from the original question, sorry)